# Why is my For loop skipping steps? R

Tags: r, algorithmic-trading

My For loop seems to be skipping steps when it should go one step at a time.

Simplifying my code:

```
for(j in 1:5){
  ventana <- spread_real[j + 1: 180 + j]
}
```

it takes the subset [j+1:180+j] from a vector 'spread_real' and assigns it to the variable 'ventana'.

But once I run the code and j equals 5, ventana gets the subset spread_real[9:190]

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I've been stuck on this for a long time now.

Comment: See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html. The sequence operator `:` has greater precedence than binary add `+`, so your subscript is equivalent to `j + (1:180) + j`.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked!!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `j + 1: 180 + j` to `(j+1):(180+j)`.

Your `for` loop is not skipping any steps, but rather your precedence is wrong; `j + 1:180 + j = (j + j) + (1:180)` which is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you!! that was the problem, now it is working!! :)